# How retrofit 2 works with several requests?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i`d like to know how retrofit 2 works with multiple requests, for example i have 10 requests from different parts of app, is retrofit processing them like a queue or simultaneously?   Thanks for help

Comment: i mean asynchronous request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit execute the request in parallel. If you want to execute requests sequentially you need to do it yourself.